# Flutter Android compile issue with admob_flutter-0.3.4 AdmobFlutterPlugin.kt: (46, 33): Overload resolution ambiguity and Type inference failed

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, admob

After upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0, Gradle Version 6.1.1, I got these errors with AdmobFlutter Plugin in the KT code:

...admob_flutter-0.3.4\android\src\main\kotlin\com\shatsy\admobflutter\AdmobFlutterPlugin.kt:
**"Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public final fun initialize(p0: Context!, p1: ((InitializationStatus!) -> Unit)!): Unit defined in com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
public open fun initialize(p0: Context!, p1: OnInitializationCompleteListener!): Unit defined in com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
public open fun initialize(p0: Context!, p1: String!): Unit defined in com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds"**

and a second error: ...admob_flutter-0.3.4\android\src\main\kotlin\com\shatsy\admobflutter\AdmobFlutterPlugin.kt: (46, 58): 
**"Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  arguments(): T!
Please specify it explicitly."**

I'm fairly new to Flutter/Dart. I haven't used Kotlin before.And it's a plugin, so I don't think I should be poking around in it too much. Would love some help of what to do.

Comment: The line 46 refers to this line:
"initialize" -> MobileAds.initialize(context, call.arguments())
inside the following function:
  override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    when(call.method) {
      "getPlatformVersion" -> result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
      "initialize" -> MobileAds.initialize(context, call.arguments())
      else -> result.notImplemented()
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the admob_flutter-0.3.4 folder in the directory:
   ..\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org
2. re do "Pub get" for pubspec.yaml.

The problem no longer occurs at compile. Perhaps there was some error in the cache files??

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. I used the following steps:

1. Go to the Flutter directory: `flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org`
2. Remove all folders that start with: `admob_flutter-...`
3. In the terminal run: `flutter pub get`

The issue is gone :)